# How can I emulate live video streaming

Tags: html, stream

I'm interested in uploading a series of files to my web server and directing viewers to page which will autoplay the videos from a specific point dependent on the current time. My intention is to create the illusion of a live stream or actual TV channel, where they are unable to control the playback, but will return to the same point if they refresh the page.

I'm having difficulty finding answers, since it's descriptively so close to an actual webcast.

Comment: One way is to use a test file.  For example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thought process on a solution.

Use the [JavaScript Date Object API](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to capture the current time

Include your video with `preload` set to true, and `controls` false

Then use [onLoad()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and setup your video in JS

```
$(video).get(0).currentTime = XX; //You need an algorithm based on the time & length of video
$(video).get(0).play();
```